# How to make running text in cardview android studio?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I want to make layout that look like this :

[image]

It similar like `Card View` and `Recycler View`
but thing that i want to ask is how to make `animation` like running text inside the `Card View`. If the text is to long then the text start moving from right to left like running text.
This is how it looks :
[image]

I already searh in google but I can't find the exactly that i want
Your help will be appreciate, 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  need to add ellipsize property with layout_width of wrap_content or size which you define :

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/attatchFilename"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chooseFile"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtMsg"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text=""
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using  `android:ellipsize="marquee"` In you `TextView`

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_text_marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:text="Scrolling Text (Marquee) in Android Application"
        android:textSize="24sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First create this animation in xml:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromXDelta="100"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toXDelta="-100" />
```

Then add the animation to the TextView:

```
textview.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scroll_animation));
```